# Windows explorer: How do I drag, paste or right click in an already full folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

In my case I use Windows 7, and I would like to focus on that OS. However it is likely the same question could also apply to other Windows versions, if not all.

Quite often I try to drag a file from one folder to another. I have two explorer windows open, and I click and hold the file from one window and drag it onto the other window.

However, sometimes the destination is already filled with subfolders to a point where there is a scrollbar, and thus no blank space left. If I drag anything into the folder now, I will likely accidentally drag the file onto one of the subfolders, in which case it will paste to that folder instead.
For now I just try to drag in between the subfolders, or I go 'up in the directory hierarchy', and drag the file onto the destination folder while I am in the folder 'above'.
**But what would be the proper way (read most efficient way) to drag files into a folder with no blank space?**

The same type of issue occurs when I want to right click in a folder to display the dropdown menu. If the folder is filled with files or subfolders, there is no black space in which I can right click.

**Is there some short key, or a method I haven't thought of, which I can easily use on any Windows 7 explorer to get to the right click menu within the current folder?**

Comment: I know that feel. Opening cmd in a folder can be a pain.

Comment: @jiggunjer Exactly! After using Windows for years how can I still be struggling with such a basic operation?!

Comment: Lol, who voted to close this question (as being *unclear*?!)  This is a damn good question and perfectly clear.

Comment: @misha256 Thank you so much for speaking up! Confidence restored :)

Comment: One of life's little frustrations that I finally sought to banish today after yet again losing a folder inside another folder unintentionally. Upvotes and thanks for the Q and A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what would be the proper way (read most efficient way) to drag files into a folder with no blank space?

There is space available, lots of it, I think you just haven't realised that drag-drop operations don't necessarily need *blank* space. I have highlighted all the hot-spots I know of that allow you to correctly "drop" items into the current folder.

[image: Windows 7 Explorer Drag-drop hot-spots]

It doesn't matter whether your View is set to Icon, Thumbnail, Details, etc., the above hot-spots always work. My favorite hot-spot is the big one at the very bottom of the window.

As for right-clicking, use this blank space:

[image: Windows 7 Explorer right-click hot-spot]

> Is there some short key... to get to the right click menu within the current folder?

There is a context-menu key on your keyboard which (usually) does the same thing as right-clicking the mouse. In your case it's no help because you'd still have to left-click the above empty space first, before pressing the key, to ensure the correct context menu comes up. So you may as well right-click the empty space. I suspect the context-menu key is intended more for folks who have a one-button mouse.

[image: Context menu key]

Comment: Good post. On point (1), I'd add column headers, you can drop stuff also over there. About (2), you get to current folder context menu by cancelling current selection; if you're in a hurry, that translates to Click, Ctrl+Click on any item, then you can RightClick (1st Click is to clear any previous selection, you don't need it if you can spot current single selected item)

Comment: The vertical space circled in the middle of pic #1 (to the left of the name column) is what helped me! Finally I can always right click to open a terminal in the current dir when it is full of files!

Answer (score 1):

Original folder - select the file or files you want to copy or move

```
Ctrl-c (keyboard shortcut to copy)
or
Ctrl-x (keyboard shortcut to cut, will move the files)
```

Go to the destination folder, make sure no folder is selected, easiest way to do this is to click once on the title bar at the top of the explorer window

```
Ctrl-v (keyboard shortcut to paste)
```

OR.....

Change the view of the destination folder to 'details' and then you can drag you files to the blank space on the far right after all the columns.  You may need to resize your destination window a little bit to see the blank space.

Comment: I agree these methods work, but somehow it feels like I'm not doing it the proper way. Do I really have to resize the window or change the view just so I can drag files into it?  Alto clicking the tile bar seems like a reasonable way to deal with this. Does anyone have an even better way? Please leave an answer. I really feel like this is a shortcoming of explorer, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: With sort of operation there is many ways to do it and there is no proper way.  Just need to find a way that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

drag the file to the main folder in the file explorer, The folders in the left side of the window[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J46Yo.png) For example: picture folder have a million folders in it. just drag the new file to the picture folder on the left instead